# How to add ip rule after dockerd is up?

Tags: docker, route, iproute

I want to add an ip rule that involves the docker0 interface. But docker0 does not exist until docker is up. ip rule will fail if docker0 does not exists. I could use a script that repeats until docker0 is added but is there a more elegant way? Like a hook / script triggered after docker is up?

Comment: Wrap the call to docker into a script, exceute the rule in the script? (effort: easy) Or write an `udev` rule? (effort: quite a bit).

Comment: First option sounds attractive but how do I wrap the call into a script? The dockerd is a daemon that only returns when it ends. But I can't put it into background as add ip rule will fail as docker0 is not created yet. So I am back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

So *something* will start your `dockerd`. I don't have a crystal ball, so I can't say what you use on your system.

If it's the `systemd`, look at the systemd configuration.

If it's something else calling `dockerd`, add a custom directory **in front** of your global `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`), put a script called `dockerd` in there, and inside the script, call the old `dockerd` with the full path.

If whatever calls it can't pick up your global path settings, you can even move the `dockerd` binary to a different place, and put a script in its place. (Though this modification won't survive package upgrades, so it's a last resort solution).

Etc., etc., ...